# Meaning of a text on a teapot (Characters identified: 石泉槐火)

Tags: translation, meaning

I have a teapot which has been in my family for about a century. Not knowing the Chinese language I tried to make something of the five characters text which is marked on it. With Google Translate I had not much success,apart from the last character which may mean (partly) spring. Altogether it should be a sentence but which one ?
Thanks for any help .

[image: Teapot]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The characters are 「石泉槐火」, which refers to the passing of winter and coming of spring. Specifically,

- 「石泉」 means *flowing of springwater* (i.e. the melting of frozen rivers and streams)
- 「槐火」 refers to a fire ritual involving the burning of the Chinese Scholar Tree ([*Styphnolobium japonicum*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Styphnolobium_japonicum))

---

In Ancient China, it is said that the monarchs conducted fire rituals involving the burning of different types of trees during the year, to protect against seasonal diseases.

> #### 《周禮・夏官》
>
> > 司爟：掌行火之政令，四時變國火以救時疾。
>
> #### *[Rites of Zhou, Offices of Summer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rites_of_Zhou)*
>
> > *Officers of the fire rituals are in charge of the royal court's decrees on conduct involving pyromancy, changing the Tree-burning Ritual throughout the year to mitigate the spread of seasonal illnesses.*

Later commentaries of the *Rites of Zhou* specified the seasonal trees to be burned:

> 春取榆柳之火， 夏取棗杏之火， 季夏取桑柘之火， 秋取柞楢之火， 冬取**槐**檀之火
>
> *During springtime, elms and willows are burned; in the summertime, jujube and apricot trees are burned; towards the end of summer, mulberry trees are burned; during autumn, oaks are burned; in the winter, **scholar trees** and rosewoods* are burned.*
>
> <sub>*The specific type of tree referred to is uncertain.</sub>

Comment: A most erudite and comprehensive answer. Thanks